# сделать merge request на GitLab через Git bash

Tags: gitlab, git-merge

Как сделать merge request через Git bash ? именно нужно через Git Bash, через сайт знаю как делается)
вообщем создал ветку , сделал команды

```
git push .
git commit -m "changed"
git push -u origin testForGitBash
```

и дальше как создать merge request? на сайте GitLab'a https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/push_options.html перепробовал все команды и никакого эффекта...

Answer (score 1):

На ГитЛаб сайте не нашел этой инфы, нашел в инете :

```
1. git pull
2. git checkout - b test
3.git add .
4.git commit -m 'explanation what is changed'
5.git request-pull master origin
6.git push -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.remove_source_branch
```